# Is the 3-sphere isomorphic to Spin(3)?

Tags: differential-geometry, spin-geometry

I am trying to learn some spin geometry stuff and getting a bit confused.  The unit quaternions can be thought of as a group structure on $S^3$ which gives the group $\text{Spin}(3)$.

Is there some sense in which $S^3$ is isomorphic to or equal to $\text{Spin}(3)$?

Comment: Usually often one thinks of $\operatorname{Spin}(3)$ as being defined as $2$-fold (and hence universal) cover of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$, rather than in terms of unit quaternions, whose relationship with the spin group $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is special for $n = 3$.

Comment: Identifying $\Bbb H$ with the space of $1 \times 1$ matrices over $\Bbb H$ identifies the group of unit quaternions as the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(1, \Bbb H)$ preserving the standard hermitian form $(x, y) \mapsto \operatorname{Re}(\bar x y)$ on $\Bbb H$; in this context the group of unit quaternions is often denoted $\operatorname{Sp}(1)$; the groups $\operatorname{Sp}(n)$ are called the *compact symplectic groups*. Less commonly these care called *quaternionic unitary group* or *hyperunitary group* and denoted $\operatorname{U}(n, \Bbb H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This group appears to possess a bunch of alternative definitions, like

- The unit quaternions
- The special unitary group $\text{SU}(2)$
- The spin group $\text{Spin}(3)$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Accidental_isomorphisms

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, I was getting a bit confused there.